# useEffect dispatch problem (you may need to add middleware)

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

**API**

```
import axios from "axios"

const url = "http://localhost:5000/posts"

export const fetchPosts = () => async () => await axios.get(url)

export const createPost = async (post) => await axios.post(url, post)
```

**ACTION**

```
export const fetchPosts = async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const {data} = await api.fetchPosts()
        dispatch({
            type: types.FETCH_POSTS,
            payload: data
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

**STORE**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './index'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

export default function configureStore() {
    return createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './Redux/store/configureStore'

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I want to make get request to my posts by axios. There is no problem in post request but I can't get one.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPosts())
  }, [dispatch])
```

When I use this method it throws this error :

Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions.

There is no any syntax or import/export mistake.

Why even if I inserted redux thunk to store it throws me this middleware error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update `fetchPosts` return a function

```
export const fetchPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const {data} = await api.fetchPosts()
        dispatch({
            type: types.FETCH_POSTS,
            payload: data
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const fetchPosts = () => async () => await axios.get(url)
```

the function above returns a promise

try

```
export const fetchPosts = async () => { 
   let res = await axios.get(url) 
   return res;
}
```

Comment: have you change fetchPost so it doesn't return a callback but a result ? (as in the example I gave)

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight problem in your action. [Action creators](https://read.reduxbook.com/markdown/part1/04-action-creators.html) are functions that return actions. You want to return an action (In this case a function) from your action creator.

So your action shoule be:

```
export const fetchPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
// Added this part        ^^^^^^ 
    try {
        const {data} = await api.fetchPosts()
        dispatch({
            type: types.FETCH_POSTS,
            payload: data
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can make this change to your code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPosts)
    // Removed the () ^
  }, [dispatch])
```